# Where is random defined with no arguments?

Tags: library

I can't seem to find `void random()` (with no arguments) defined in the library and yet my sketches seem to compile just fine when calling `random()` with no arguments.

I've found [random with 1 argument](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/WMath.cpp#L35) and [random with 2 arguments](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/WMath.cpp#L43) but no cases of random with no arguments.

Is `random()` defined in the library with no arguments?

If so, where is it defined?

If it isn't, what could explain how my code compiles despite me not providing any arguments?

Comment: It's defined in stdlib.h

Comment: @sempaiscuba Sadly Ignacio got there 8 minutes sooner, but that is indeed correct.

Comment: Sorry about that. The question came up in review, so I added the comment rather than an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's defined [in the libc](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdlib.html#ga114aeb1751119382aaf3340355b22cfd), in `stdlib.h`.

Comment: That explains why I couldn't find it in the Arduino github's source code.